# spring security- catch exception inside the authentication failure url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I use class which is implements UserDetails for authentication. Inside that I pass my custom exceptions, just like attempts exceeds instead of userNotFoundException.

I want to know how to catch this exception in the authentication failure url.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have a class that implements `UserDetailsService` and you are throwing a custom exception that you want to catch in `AuthenticationFailureHandler`. If this is the case,  your custom exception should extend [AuthenticationException](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/AuthenticationException.html) and login filter will pass it to `onAuthenticationFailure` method of `AuthenticationFailureHandler`.